# Using `io.sockets.emit` in the router. What if socket establishing is not finished before it?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, asynchronous, socket.io

I'm using `io.sockets.emit` in the router like

```
  db.SomeModel.find({},
    function(err, modelDate) { 
      io.sockets.emit('eventName', modelData);
    }
  );
```

What would happen if a socket took like 10sec (just an example) to be established, and before it is established I try to emit something. Would it give some `undefined` error or..? I'm new to node and asynchronous programming in general. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if socket establishing is not finished before it?

It will just be skipped and no data will be sent to a socket that is has not yet established its connection.

`io.sockets.emit()` loops through a list of connected sockets and sends to each one individually.  If a socket is not done connecting, then it won't be in the list that socket.io is iterating through so no data will be sent to it.